# A simple expression to map $\mathbb N^*$ bijectively to $\mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, arithmetic

Let $\mathbb N = \{ 1,2,3,\ldots \}$, then by the well-known "Cantor"-Scheme we have $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \cong \mathbb N$. But even nicer is that we can write this scheme $\varphi : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ as a simple function<sup>1</sup> (quadratic polynomial)
$$
 \varphi(n,m) = n + \sum_{i=1}^{n+m-2} i = \frac{1}{2}(n+m-1)(n+m-2) + n.
$$
which could be seen by looking at the infinite grid $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ the right way quite simply<sup>2</sup>. Setting
$$
 (n,m,k) \mapsto \varphi(\varphi(n,m), k)
$$
and so on we see that $\mathbb N^k \cong \mathbb N$ and we still got a simple formula. But now consider
$$
 \mathbb N^* := \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb N^k
$$
which as a countable union of countable sets must themselve be countable. But beside this abstract proof, does there exists some simple (maybe polynomial)
function which realises this bijection?

Denote by $p_n$ the $n$-th prime number and define $\psi$ by $\psi(n_1, \ldots, n_k) := 2^{n_1} 3^{n_2} \cdots p_k^{n_k}$, this gives such a correspondence based on the unique prime factorisation, but maybe you know some simpler ones, that could also be evaluated fast on a computer (computing the $n$ prime is not computationally simple).

---

**Footnotes:**

1. For $\varphi : \mathbb N_0 \times \mathbb N_0 \to \mathbb N_0$ we have
   $$
    \varphi(n,m) = n + \sum_{i=1}^{n+m} i = n + \frac{1}{2}(n+m)(n+m+1).
   $$
2. For $(n,m)$ consider the diagonal where $i + j = m + n$ and sum everything
   underneath this diagonal, this is exactly $\sum_{i=1}^{n+m}$, after this add $n$ to move on this diagonal to the right point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following map $f:\mathbb{N}^* \to \mathbb{N}$ should be a bijection. If $u$ is the empty word, let $f(u) = 0$ and if  $u = (n_0, n_1, \dotsm, n_k) \in \mathbb{N}$, let
$$
f(u) = 10^{n_0}10^{n_1} \dotsm 10^{n_k}
$$
where the right hand side is the binary representation of an integer.

Comment: This looks really clean and nice but if the natural numbers are defined as positive integers, then it doesn't seem like you are mapping anything to odd integers, or strings of 1's for example. But I think it works if you define $N^*$ to include 0 as an entry and you subtract 1 from the function value to get a natural number that could be 0.

Comment: For me, the set natural numbers is the set of nonnegative integers, which includes $0$. Thus $f(0,0) = 11$.

Comment: @RobArthan: $f((0,0)) = 11, f((0) = 1, f(()) = 0$, so this is fine. What he does is coding each tupel by representing each number unary (i.e. $n \leftrightarrow 0^n$) and using $1$ as a separating sign, and in that way each binary digit/sequence (without leading zeros) occurs too, giving a surjection. In retrospect a really simple idea :)

Comment: @J.E.-Pin: In my post I wrote $\mathbb N = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $\mathbb N_0 = \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$. But indeed that doesn't matter that much conceptually, otherwise $(n_1,\ldots, n_k) \mapsto 10^{n_1-1}10^{n_2-1}\cdots 10^{n_k-1}$ would work too. Also note that I do not included the empty word in the union $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb N^k$, I know this is not in concordance with standard practice in string theory/computer science, so sorry, but again this does not change anything conceputally much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea which should work.

Let $n >0$ be a positive integer.

Define $k_0=n$, and recursively, as long as $k_j \neq 0$ define 
$$
k_{j} =2^{k_{j+1}} m_{j+1} \, \mbox { with } m_{j+1} \mbox{ odd }
$$

This process ends after $t$ steps, when $k_t=0$, or equivalently $k_{t-1}$ is odd.

Now define 
$$f(n) =( \frac{m_1-1}{2}, \frac{m_2-1}{2},.., \frac{m_t-1}{2} ) \in \mathbb N^t$$

I think it is easy to show that this is a bijection as you want. Note that $f$ maps the odd numbers to $\mathbb N$, the numbers for which the power of two is odd to $\mathbb N^2$ and so on.

This is easy to compute, as all you need is to figure the power of two in an integer.